# RosCore on Android fails

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have put together the most basic project I could to show this error.
https://github.com/FutureHax/BrokenRos

When ros core is started on the Android device, message fail to be passed through.

Start the app, use the MasterChooser to start a new public master.
Point your computer to the ros core instance on your phone.
Attempt to push a message.

What I see when attempting this steps is the following.

```
03-16 16:51:16.012  30235-30842/com.cloudspace.coretester E/XmlRpcErrorLogger﹕ No such handler: system.multicall
org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcNoSuchHandlerException: No such handler: system.multicall
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.AbstractReflectiveHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractReflectiveHandlerMapping.java:214)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:45)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)
```

I have seen a few other issues mention this "system.multicall" line, but none have been resolved.

Am I doing something incorrect or is there a bug in the ros code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205122/roscore-on-android-fails/) by [r2doesinc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21122/r2doesinc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-17**:
If you really feel this is a bug, perhaps reporting it directly on the [rosjava](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava/issues) and/or [android_core](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/issues) issue trackers would be more efficient.

**Comment by [mmore](https://answers.ros.org/users/22937/mmore/) on 2016-02-26**:
I have the same problem using roscore on Android. This seems to be a bug in ROS Java: [roslaunch uses XML-RPC function system.multicall - which is not supported by rosjava](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/84).

Have somebody any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would seem to be fixed with the merge of [rosjava/rosjava_core#273](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/pull/273).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0